# Select next element, starting from certain element

Tags: jquery

I have two `radio` buttons on my page. When i select the first i want it to disable a certain set of `input` fields inside a div. When i select the second `radio`, i want it to disable other elements. But these elements aren't nested inside the `div` where the `radio` buttons reside in.

I can't seem to figure out a good way to disable the right elements.

Here's an example:
http://tinkerbin.com/tvx5EwHR

Anyone any idea how i can disable the right input fields?

Please note that i rather not use `parent().parent()` as a solution. Because this would easily break my JS when i later on decide to change the DOM layout a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to do anything complicated with selectors, I would just update the DOM a little bit.  Something like

```
<input type="radio" ... data-disable="element1"/>
...
<div class="element1">
...
```

Then, in jQuery you can get the class of the element to disable with `$(this).data('disable')` after first enabling all of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one http://tinkerbin.com/xQjeYD6C

```
$(function() {
  $('.opt1').click(function() {
    $('.elements1').show();
    $('.elements2').hide();
  });

  $('.opt2').click(function() {
    $('.elements1').hide();
    $('.elements2').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: now please check or otherwise please click run button and then check

Comment: When i click the radio in the first container, then it also hides the elements in the 2nd container. I don't want that to happen. The radio should only hide/show the elements in the container that they belong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have you want to enable / disable the whole div associated with Radio buttons then this might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340449/how-can-i-disable-a-div-tag-on-my-html-page-using-javascript